# Windows Timer Resolution in Kernel Mode

Tags: windows, timer, kernel

Is there any way to check the system timer resolution in kernel mode? We noticed the timer resolution is changed in our test systems during bootup (i.e. driver load) but cannot figure out when and where in the driver it is happening.

Also, what kernel mode calls into Windows can alter timer resolution? Does initializing a periodic timer of 1ms automatically change the timer resolution to 1ms from the default 15.6ms?

EDIT: We know it's changed by one particular driver which we have symbols for. But we want to dig deeper and find out which part of the driver is calling for the timer resolution changed. I'm thinking something alone the line of setting different breakpoints in WinDbg, and then somehow check what the timer resolution is via WinDbg. Is that at all possible? Is the timer resolution info inside any OS defined structure?